# Understanding this perl solution

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

I am trying to solve a code golfing exercise which involves taking input the number of test cases, followed by an integer in each line for each test case.

In my quest to get the shortest possible solution I came across [this](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?Central%20binomial%20coefficient%202/tails_1304672418&pl) solution:

```
#!perl -lp
use bigint;$_=???<>+1:bnok{2*$_}$_
```

I am very new perl, hence I am not getting how this code is actually working. I will be grateful if somebody help me figure this out.

PS: [Asked and closed at codegolf.stackexhange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/how-to-take-t-test-case-input-output-in-perl-via-perl-lp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few tools for figuring out Perl golf.  One is [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret) which documents the "secret operators" and tricks used by many Perl golfers.

For this particular code, it's also important to understand what [`-p` does](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).  It wraps the code in a bunch of other code which can then be exploited for golfing purposes.

Finally, the ultimate tool for unpacking Perl golf is [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse).  This translates how Perl understood the code back into human readable Perl with indentation and the like.  The -p option makes B::Deparse add parenthesis even when they're not necessary which can help clarify precedence.  The -d option gives a more accurate representation of objects.  What objects?  Observe.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p,-d
#!perl -lp
use bigint;$_=???<>+1:bnok{2*$_}$_

Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at - line 2.
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
use bigint;
LINE: while (defined(($_ = <ARGV>))) {
    chomp($_);
    BEGIN {
        $^H{'bigint'} = '1';
        $^H{'binary'} = 'CODE(0x7fc88ba3d580)';
        $^H{'float'} = 'CODE(0x7fc88ba3d478)';
        $^H{'integer'} = 'CODE(0x7fc88b298428)';
    }
    ($_ = (?? ? (<ARGV> + bless( {"sign" => "+","value" => [1]}, 'Math::BigInt' )) : (bnok {
        (bless( {"sign" => "+","value" => [2]}, 'Math::BigInt' ) * $_)
    } $_)));
}
continue {
    (print($_) or die("-p destination: $!\n"));
}
- syntax OK
```

A few of the more esoteric things this reveals...

- ??? is the [`?PATTERN?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator plus the `?:` ternary operator.  Specifically, `??` is the condition for the ternary.
- `??` works just like `//` but it will only match once until `reset` is called.  Because reset is never called in this program, it will only match once for this program.  `//` will match on anything.
- `use bigint` turns all integers into Math::BigInt objects.
- `bnok` is the binomial coefficient method from [Math::BigInt](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt).
- `bnok` is being used as an indirect method call on the integers (which are really Math::BigInt objects).  Indirect method calls are of the form `method $object @args` so `bnok{2*$_}$_` is actually `(2*$_)->bnok($_)` which is the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

The meat of the program can be understood a bit easier with some indentation and vertical whitespace.  An editor with good paren matching is all you need to work them out.

```
(
    $_ =
      (?? ? (<ARGV> + bless( {"sign" => "+","value" => [1]}, 'Math::BigInt' ))
          : (bnok {(bless( {"sign" => "+","value" => [2]}, 'Math::BigInt' ) * $_) } $_)
      )
);
```

- Because `??` will only match once for the whole program, it's used to skip the first line which is the number of tests.
- After the first line, `??` will be false which will trigger the `bnok` calculation.

There is one detail I have not worked out.  Why is it `<>+1` and not `<>`?  It seems to suppress a blank line but I don't know why.

Comment: I have greatly expanded my answer to reveal an almost complete solution.

Comment: I imagine the +1 is for supplying a scalar context.